# Excess decimal points showing on QGIS layout grid

Tags: qgis, layouts, grids-graticules, layout-manager

I am using QGIS 3.8.1.

The intervals of my grid are 1.2cm and the labels are set at a 0.6cm offset so they are placed in the middle. I used the draw coordinates custom option to enter my own coordinates rather than from a coordinate reference system. The code I used is as follows and the problem I am encountering can be seen in the image below.

```
CASE 
WHEN @grid_axis = 'y'    
THEN substr('ONMLKJIHGFEDCBA', (@grid_number + 0.6 ) / 1.2 , 1)     
WHEN @grid_axis = 'x'    
THEN (@grid_number + 0.6) / 1.2    
END
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `round()` function to make sure no decimal shows:

Modify your expression like this:

```
CASE 
WHEN @grid_axis = 'y'    
THEN substr('ONMLKJIHGFEDCBA', (@grid_number + 0.6 ) / 1.2 , 1)     
WHEN @grid_axis = 'x'    
THEN (round(@grid_number,0) + 0.6) / 1.2    
END
```

The values should be rounded to the nearest integer.

[image]

Comment: Ok this took off the decimal places but now replaced all my grid labels to 1

Comment: @TonyBrown There has to be something else going on with your expression. I tried your setup with two grids, one offset 0.6cm for the labels, and I had to use `THEN round(@grid_number,0)` for the X axis. Check screenshot in edited answer.

Comment: You are correct and I fixed it to be identical to yours. It is now missing every number which is a multiple of 6 for some reason.